# How to create shopify ScriptTag that would be used without asyncLoad wrapper?

Tags: shopify

Shopify does wrap all scripts added through [ScriptTag](http://api.shopify.com/scripttag.html) API into special asyncLoad function. While it makes sense in many circumstances there still situations when you need script tag inserted directly into the header.

For example [Optimizely](http://apps.shopify.com/optimizely) wouldn't work that smooth if there wasn't other way to insert script tag, i.e. somehow theirs script appears in the store front independently, i.e. without asyncLoad function.

**How would I do the same?**

One option is to parse and then send back current theme, but it looks weird and not quite reliable, and according my research [Optimizely](http://apps.shopify.com/optimizely) does know another approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I was able to get in touch with Optimizely, here is their's response:

> We actually partnered with Shopify to get our snippet added to the page in this way by default. I don’t think there is a simple way to work around the async limitation otherwise.

and here is Shopify's response:

> Unfortunately this was a one-off hack-y fix, and not something that we're open to doing again at this time.

So, for now the only reliable way to work around the async limitation is to **instruct users to place the script into current theme** as others applications does.